# HtmlUnit HtmlSelect doesn't trigger events

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am building a spider for a web site that has two combo boxes, the first one populates the second one.

this it is done with a javascript:

```
  <script>var initAutocomplete2Flag = 1;

    $(document).ready(function () {


        if ($('#gender').val() == 'Female') {

            marital_options = '';
            var selected = '';
            $.each(marital_status_female, function (index, value) {
                if (value == 1) {
                    selected = 'selected="selected"';
                } else {
                    selected = '';
                }
                marital_options += '<option ' + selected + ' value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });
            $('#marital_status').html('<select class="form-control" id="marital_status" name="marital_status">' + marital_options + '</select>');

        } else {
            marital_options = '';
            var selected = '';
            $.each(marital_status_male, function (index, value) {
                if (value == 1) {
                    selected = 'selected="selected"';
                } else {
                    selected = '';
                }
                marital_options += '<option ' + selected + ' value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });
            $('#marital_status').html('<select class="form-control" id="marital_status" name="marital_status">' + marital_options + '</select>');
        }

        $('#gender').change(function () {

            if ($('#gender').val() == 'Female') {

                marital_options = '';
                var selected = '';
                $.each(marital_status_female, function (index, value) {
                    if (value == 1) {
                        selected = 'selected="selected"';
                    } else {
                        selected = '';
                    }
                    marital_options += '<option ' + selected + ' value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                });
                $('#marital_status').html('<select class="form-control" id="marital_status" name="marital_status">' + marital_options + '</select>');

            } else {
                marital_options = '';
                var selected = '';
                $.each(marital_status_male, function (index, value) {
                    if (value == 1) {
                        selected = 'selected="selected"';
                    } else {
                        selected = '';
                    }
                    marital_options += '<option ' + selected + ' value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                });
                $('#marital_status').html('<select class="form-control" id="marital_status" name="marital_status">' + marital_options + '</select>');
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

this is my code

```
import org.junit.Test;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlOption;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect;

public class BugTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.getDefault())) {

            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);      
            webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

            final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://54.233.181.233/untitle.html");

            final HtmlSelect gender = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"gender\"]");
            gender.setSelectedAttribute(gender.getOptionByValue("Male"),Boolean.TRUE);
            gender.setSelectedAttribute(gender.getOptionByValue("Female"),Boolean.TRUE);
            final HtmlSelect education = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"education\"]");

            final HtmlSelect marital_status = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"marital_status\"]");
            HtmlOption option = marital_status.getOptionByText("Other");
            marital_status.setSelectedAttribute(option,Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `marital_status.getOptions()` it is empty.

Any clue how to make it work?

Comment: Please use latest version, and provide a compete case (with URL).

Comment: Hi @AhmedAshour, just added a Junit and the URL inside it. Will be easy for reproduce it. I'm using 2.26 version

Answer (score 0):

With [latest build](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts), you can get the `options`, however there are other errors.

You can get around them by `.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)`.

The two errors:

1. > TypeError: Cannot call method "post" of undefined (https://tutasawc.ucontactcloud.com/webchatclient/integrawebchat.js#91)

   and by looking into the `integrawebchat.js`: `endSession` is called even though `windowProxy` is not set, because `sessionStorage.getItem("integrachatstarted")` evaluates to `false`.

   I am not sure if this is a production website, and this is a valid error or not.

2. > No permitted "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

   Again, I am not sure about this one, and whether further investigations should be done  or not.

Comment: thank you @AhamedAshour, 
but I need the JavaScriptEnabled in true ... because a previous page that has a button that doesn't work if the JavaScriptEnable it is disabled.

What can I do ? Do you know why the combo it is not working with JavaScript enable ? 

thank you